# WebSphare MQ triggers using publish/subscribe

Tags: ibm-mq

We are migrating from our legacy COM+ client to Restful service. Our legacy client were using [WebSphere MQ triggering feature](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q026910_.htm) with amqmdnet.dll for MQSeries for .Net platform. I couldn't find any easy way to invoke response handler in our Restful service from MQ trigger. Info: I'm not looking for workarounds like trigger (by MQ) simple program which create request to restful service - it might introduce security risks and additional maintenance. Looks like we cannot use that feature for Restful service.

I have found [HTTP Bridge](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q033180_.htm). Http Bridge doesn't support triggering but has support for [publish/subscriber](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q033220_.htm) pattern and can be easily integrated with Restful service. The point is I'm not familiar with WebSphere MQ. I wonder whether it is possible to substitute MQ triggering by using publish/subscribe pattern of HTTP Bridge. Can anyone confirm that?

Comment: Triggering is for starting a process, while publish/subscribe is a messaging pattern, so I don't understand why you are thinking about them in the same relation. If you cannot use triggering, than you need to have a process running and listening for messages, it makes no difference in this regard whether this process uses point to point or publish subscribe pattern.

Comment: @Attila Repasi: Thank You for fast answer. I relate them because old implementation had triggering. In new infrastructure we want to get rid of COM+ objects and relay on restful service to handle responses/requests. Can we think of restful service as a processes  where subscriber(point) could be a restful method listening for messages?

Comment: I understand that your old application had triggering but publish/subscribe has nothing to do with triggering, it cannot be used to implement triggering. Your service needs to subscribe for messages an to be active to receive them.

Comment: Are you sure it's not possible? Before we had a program(responseDelegator) which was invoked by triggering(that's how triggering works). I want to move the logic from program(responseDelegator) to webapi method. And subscribe that webapi method for messages. Are you sure it will not replace triggering if we configure it like that. I'm not sure what do you mean by active. The webapi service will be an application hosted on one server. It should be running all the time but there might be some downtime.

Comment: By active I mean, that your application needs to be running, and have a connection open to the queue manager, have the topic or queue open where you are receiving messages and get messages. And without triggering, none of these steps will be triggered by the queue manager.

Comment: And after you can make your application handle this you should decide whether to use point to point messaging or publish/subscribe messaging. Publish/subscribe messaging is not a tool for triggering any of the above steps, it is a tool to abstract the destination of messages and allow applications to dynamically set when they want to receive certain messages.